# Load custom maintenance page to Heroku

Tags: heroku, maintenance-mode

Heroku can display custom maintenance page:

```
heroku config:set MAINTENANCE_PAGE_URL=http://some_server/my_page.html
```

This requires presence of some website where the page will be always online.

Could the maintenance page be loaded into Heroku once and forever?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, since there will be no way for the Heroku router to show it if there is a maintenance problem *on Heroku*.

The canonical way is to put that page on Amazon S3, or any other provider that can serve static pages.

Answer (score -1):

goto app-> setting -> reveal config vars 
add new row
key =MAINTENANCE_PAGE_URL 
value =  any url u want to open

Comment: Could I know that how to revert back to show default page after setting this config ? I tried to do that by deleting the key. But it still display the custom site.

Comment: just remove the key, and then restart the heroku server, it should reflect ur change in sometime, it takes time

Comment: OK. I'll try. Thanks.